Jmeter gRPC sampler is throwing error : GRPCSampler parsing exception
While using JMeter gRPC sampler i.e. GRPC Request getting error, enter image description here
GRPCSampler parsing exception: An unknown exception occurred before the GRPC request was initiated, See response body for the stack trace.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:495)
    at com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.getPort(HostAndPort.java:110)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.core.grpc.ChannelFactory.createChannelBuilder(ChannelFactory.java:51)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.core.grpc.ChannelFactory.createChannel(ChannelFactory.java:39)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.core.ClientCaller.createDynamicClient(ClientCaller.java:154)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.core.ClientCaller.init(ClientCaller.java:96)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.core.ClientCaller.<init>(ClientCaller.java:53)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.initGrpcClient(GRPCSampler.java:81)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.initGrpcInCurrentThread(GRPCSampler.java:203)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.initGrpcRequestSampler(GRPCSampler.java:133)
    at vn.zalopay.benchmark.GRPCSampler.sample(GRPCSampler.java:90)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(null:-1)

I have created a service in Asp.net with below .proto file
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcGreeter";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}

I tried to run this in JMeter with plugin i.e. GRPC Request but I'm getting the status code 400 with above mentioned error.
enter image description here
@Dmitri T

I think you need to remove http:// from the "Server Name or IP" input, you're supposed to provide either IP address or DNS hostname there.
Going forward consider enabling JMeter debug logging, this way you will have way more information allowing to quickly get to the root cause of the issue.

This solution didn't work, start getting 500 status code after removing https:// from the "Server Name or IP" and provided IP address.
